# How do I check if a function is called in a method of a class?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I need to check to see if a specific function "oscp.deactivate_user()" is being called in an instance of a method call delete()

Here's what I have so far, the assert fails, when it shouldn't be.

```
@mock.patch.object(AuthUser, 'delete')
@mock.patch('oscp.deactivate_user')
def test_delete(self, deactivate_user_mock, delete_mock):
    """Test the delete() method in AuthUser"""
    authUserObject = mock.Mock()
    authUserObject.oscp_id = 4

    """If delete_from_oscp = True && oscp_id isset"""
    delete_mock_instance = delete_mock(self, True, authUserObject, oscp_id=4)
    delete_mock_instance.delete_mock.assert_called_once_with(self)
```

Comment: Where in this code are you calling the `delete` method?  It looks like you're mocking the `delete` method when you shouldn't be...

Comment: @mgilson I don't want to actually call the delete method, that's why I'm passing a mock of it with "@mock.patch.object(AuthUser, 'delete')"

Comment: But if `AuthUser.delete` is what calls `oscp.deactivate_user`, then when you mock `AuthUser.delete`, you certainly _won't_ be calling `oscp.deactivate_user` because how would the `Mock` know that it's supposed to call that method? (hence the failed assertion).  I think you want to _not_ mock AuthUser.delete`, but you _do_ want to mock `oscp.deactivate_user`.

Comment: @mgilson Ahhh, makes sense, XGooglers are always helpful :) Thanks!